# how to add multi functions to the same useState on Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am a starter on React! Just learning right now

How can I set multi functions to change a single data? I mean, I created a reset function below which has the purpuse to reset the numbers. It is working fine!

Just for an example, I also want to create a function to change the 'hour', 'minute' and 'second' to the value '2'.

which is the best way to do it?

It will have two buttons and each button will activate the 'resetTime' or 'changeToTwoTime'.

```
//data()
const [hour, resetHour] = useState(4)
const [minute, resetMinute] = useState(8)
const [second, resetSecond] = useState(12)

// methods
const resetTime = () => {
    resetHour(0)
    resetMinute(0)
    resetSecond(0)
}

return (
        <div className="p-3">
             <MainButton 
                  variantButton="outline-success"
                  textButton="START"
                  functionButton={resetTime}
              /> 
              <MainButton 
                  variantButton="outline-success"
                  textButton="START"
                  functionButton={changeToTwoTime}
              />
        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just for an example, I also want to create a function to change the 'hour', 'minute' and 'second' to the value '2'.

You don't need actually to duplicate the function. You could just simply adjust your function so it accepts an argument, which will be the *value* of the *date*.

```
const setTime = (value = 0) => {
  resetHour(value);
  resetMinute(value);
  resetSecond(value);
}
```

The `value` argument is optional. If the function is called without any arguments, it will simply *reset* the times to `0`. If `value` is passed, it will set the timers to that specified `value`.

```
   <div className="p-3">
         <MainButton 
              variantButton="outline-success"
              textButton="START"
              functionButton={() => setTime()} // reset timers
          /> 
          <MainButton 
              variantButton="outline-success"
              textButton="START"
              functionButton={() => setTime(2)} // set it to 2
          />
    </div>
```

Comment: This awser my question! Tks ;)